# Delete rows in a specific range that contains blank values

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to delete the rows in a specified cell range that contains blank values.

Tried this:

```
sub TestDeleteRow()
    Set exlTest = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathExc)
    objExcel.Application.Visible = True

    objExcel.Sheets("FNR_CHECK").Range("E3:G13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Msgbox "Rows deleted", vbOKOnly, "TA Balance Sheet"
end sub
```

I'm getting an error in the line

```
objExcel.Sheets("FNR_CHECK").Range("E3:G13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Saying subscript out of range

Comment: Is this a one time thing?  If so just sort on that column and delete all the blank rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `Range` and use the [`SpecialCells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff196157.aspx) function to select blank cells within that range. Then, apply the `EntireRow` property to select and delete the rows.

For example, to delete the rows that have blanks in column A:

```
Const xlCellTypeBlanks = 4

objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Hi Bond. Thanks for your reply. I am still learning and was wondering why do I have to specify the Const as equal to 4.

Comment: I have edited my main comment to show you the error I'm getting

Comment: If you're using VBScript, constants like `xlCellTypeBlanks` won't be predefined. You need to define them yourself. `xlCellTypeBlanks` is just a constant/enum in Excel having a value of `4`.

Comment: I have edited my main post to show the code I'm trying and the error I'm getting

Comment: Did you add the constant like I showed in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is small sub which will loop through the column A (Change it to your selected column) and it will first trim the cell value in case if you have space or anything and then it will delete the entire row if blank value is found.

```
Sub DeleteRowsThatLookEmpty()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim Rng As Range, ix As Long
    Set Rng = Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange) 'You can specify the sheet you want and change the column
    For ix = Rng.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Trim(Replace(Rng.Item(ix).Text, Chr(160), Chr(32))) = "" Then
            Rng.Item(ix).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: He appears to be using VBScript. The  `Application` object, types like `Range` and `Long`, and constants like `xlCalculationManual` and `xlCalculationAutomatic` won't be available.

Comment: Didn't notice that. In that case your solution should do the trick.